# RxPY - How to use stop_and_wait?

Tags: python, rx-py

I tried to translate the following JavaScript code example in Python:

```
import Rx from "rx"

let source = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .timestamp()
  .controlled();

source.stopAndWait().subscribe(
  (result) => console.log("onNext: ", result),
  (error) => console.log("onError: ", error),
  () => console.log("Done!")
);
```

The snippet was taken from the [RxJS Release Notes](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/releases/tag/v2.3.22). My Python interpretation looks like the following:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from rx import Observable


source = Observable.interval(1000).timestamp().controlled()
source.stop_and_wait().subscribe(
    on_next=lambda x: print("on_next %s" % x),
    on_error=lambda e: print("on_error %s" % e)
)
```

Unfortunately, while JavaScript version works just fine the Python version fails due to the fact that *'StopAndWaitObservable' object has no attribute 'subscription'.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for the issue was merged into the rx library development line. With the fix Python version works just like JavaScript one.